# Missing or conflicting dependencies for Anko floatingActionButton

Tags: android, user-interface, dependencies, kotlin, anko

After following [this slightly outdated tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-ui-with-kotlin-and-anko/), I'm stuck trying to use `org.jetbrains.anko.design.floatingActionButton`. The error is:

> Cannot access class 'android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies.

#### build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.50'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### build.gradle (App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.co.danielstanton.todoapp.todoapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"

    // Anko + Android Support Libraries:

    // Appcompat-v7 (Anko Commons and Layouts)
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version"

    // CardView-v7
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-cardview-v7:$anko_version"

    // Design
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design-coroutines:$anko_version"

    // GridLayout-v7
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-gridlayout-v7:$anko_version"

    // Percent
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-percent:$anko_version"

    // RecyclerView-v7
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"

    // Support-v4 (Anko Commons and Layouts)
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"
}
```

#### MainUI.kt

```
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ListView
import org.jetbrains.anko.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.appcompat.v7.toolbar
import org.jetbrains.anko.design.floatingActionButton
import org.jetbrains.anko.sdk25.coroutines.onItemLongClick

class MainUI(val todoAdapter: TodoAdapter) : AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>): View = with(ui) {
        return relativeLayout {
            var todoList : ListView? =null

            //textView displayed when there is no task
            val hintListView = textView("What's your Todo List for today?") {
                textSize = 20f
            }.lparams {
                centerInParent()
            }

            //function to show or hide above textView
            fun showHideHintListView(listView: ListView) {
                if (getTotalListItems(listView)>0) {
                    hintListView.visibility = View.GONE
                } else {
                    hintListView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }

            //layout to display ListView
            verticalLayout {
                todoList=listView {
                    adapter = todoAdapter
                    onItemLongClick { adapterView, view, i, l ->
                        val options = listOf("Completed","In Progress","Not Started","Delete")
                        selector("Task Options", options) {dialogInterface, j ->
                            if (j == 3) {
                                var task=adapter.getItem(i)
                                todoAdapter?.delete(i)
                                showHideHintListView(this@listView)
                                longToast("Task ${task} has been deleted")
                            }else{
                                longToast("Task ${adapter.getItem(i).toString()} has been marked as \"${options[j]}\"")
                            }
                        }
                        true
                    }
                }
            }.lparams {
                margin = dip(5)
            }

            //Add task FloatingActionButton at bottom right
            floatingActionButton {  // <-- HERE
                imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_input_add
                onClick {
                    val adapter = todoList?.adapter as TodoAdapter
                    alert {
                        customView {
                            verticalLayout {
                                toolbar {
                                    id = R.id.dialog_toolbar
                                    lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
                                    backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.colorAccent)
                                    title = "What's your next milestone?"
                                    setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, android.R.color.white))
                                }
                                val task = editText {
                                    hint = "To do task "
                                    padding = dip(20)
                                }
                                positiveButton("Add") {
                                    if(task.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                                        toast("Oops!! Your task says nothing!")
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        adapter.add(task.text.toString())
                                        showHideHintListView(todoList!!)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.show()
                }
            }.lparams {
                //setting button to bottom right of the screen
                margin = dip(10)
                alignParentBottom()
                alignParentEnd()
                alignParentRight()
                gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END
            }
        }.apply {
            layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(matchParent, matchParent)
                    .apply {
                        leftMargin = dip(5)
                        rightMargin = dip(5)
                    }
        }

    }

    //function to get total number of items in list
    fun getTotalListItems(list: ListView?) = list?.adapter?.count ?: 0
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your app `build.gradle` file

[image]I think you are doing changes in https://github.com/Kotlin/anko this project. 
You need to follow this https://github.com/ankul09jain/To-doApp

And

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, there are a fair few bugs in this tutorial, so I'm going to drop it

Comment: It's not clear which of these settings is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to fix it you only need to add the Android Support Design dependency. Because, in your case, you are trying to add a FAB using Anko Layout library and it dependes on the supra cited library.

Just add the following to your app dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```